# Installer for ISDeploymentWizard.exe

Tags: deployment, sql-server-2012, wizard, ssis-2012

Is anyone aware of an installer (msi or otherwise) that drops the SSIS Deployment Wizard executable (ISDeploymentWizard.exe) onto a server (generally found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn).  We have a web server (we use this as our TFS Agent) that we want to deploy our SSIS 2012 packages from - it is a fairly vanilla server (with IIS, .NET, etc) and hence we don't want a fully blown install of SSIS and/or VS2012 (SSDT) just to deploy SSIS packages.

I realise we can use T-SQL (which requires an instance level perm'd user as an OPENROWSET BULK  import is used) and/or MOM to deploy SSIS packages to a remote SQL Server 2012 instance however the preference is to use the SSIS Deployment Wizard

I would have thought ISDeploymentWizard.exe would have been part of the SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35580) however it is unclear exactly whether this is the case and indeed which msi it would belong to

Answer (score 5):

I needed the same ISDeploymentWizard.exe on our build server.  We didn't want a full installation of SQLServer on the build box. Using the ISO (en_sql_server_2012_developer_edition_with_sp1_x64_dvd_1228540) from MSDN subscriptions

I chose "Integration Services" [image: Choose Integration Services]

However, if you look thru the files in the ISO there is

```
sql_is.msi
```

Which is likely the MSI you looking for.   That placed isdeploymentwizard.exe in for out 64-bit machine.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe
```

Comment: Unfortunately the sql_is.msi is expecting certain flags and conditions so you do have to go through the painful hazing ritual of installing the setup files and waiting until you can get to the above screen.